# Autocomplete Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete Jquery from the following URL:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I am making my project in `MVC 3.0 (Razor)`
In this I am displaying list of names from the database and its running fine.
Now I want to show this whole  list in the div according to my project requirement.

Please help how can I display the Autocomplete data in the div.

Comment: So what's the problem? What has got you stuck in completing your project?

Comment: I dont know how to do this.I want a  hint on this .

Comment: Well, a starting point is this example : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote You should return your list as JSON so that the autocomplete plugin can do it's job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the [jQuery UI documentation (remote example)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote):

```
$(function() {

    // This function sets the results inside a div with id = 'log'
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
    }


    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});

<div id="log"></div>
```